# Size of a request header field exceeds server limit

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

i have android app send JSON data to php web service running on **WAMP Server.**

when i send many records via JSON, i have an error:

```
"Bad Request 
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. 
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit."
```

i was changed the *configuration* in **php.ini** like
**upload_max_file_size** to **64M** and **upload_max_filesize** to **64M**

How i can solve that please ?

Comment: Your sever software, what is it? nginx, apache, etc?

Comment: apache @AhmetErkanÇELİK

Answer (score 6):

It is because your http web service (apache?) does not allow requests with data more than LimitRequestFieldSize parameter (default is 8190 bytes)

Seems that one of your JSON request is too big or summ of Cookies data is too large and web service block it.

By the way increasing LimitRequestFieldSize is not a good idea, because of risk of DOS attacks.

Try to minimize/clear your cookies, or simplify Json request.

Comment: This solved it for me. I had the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You try incrase LimitRequestFieldSize option  httpd.conf or .htaccess file.

Usage is here: [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize)

Comment: httpd.conf doesn't have LimitRequestLine or LimitRequestFieldSiz
Can I add it to httpd.conf and if i can, how i can doing that ?

Comment: you can append a line:
LimitRequestFieldSize 65536

Answer (score 1):

if you need to transfer big data (between APIs with JSON in your case for example), rather than using a GET request and posting the data in headers, use POST request and send the data in body.

With POST, you can still use headers to validate tokens or small data but again post the big JSON data that will not fit in headers within POST body.

Here is a complete system for you to POST JSON data with PHP:

```
### Sender PHP Side:
# Core function that sends big data with POST:
function curl_post($url, $header, $data){
    $CURL = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($CURL);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($CURL, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($CURL);
    return array($http_code, $result);
}

# Prepare your data and send:
$url = "https://example.com/api.php";
$header = array(
    "Content-Type: text/html",
    "verify: <your fixed code to verify the request is legit>",
    "anything: <you can send anything with headers here but the text you send should be SMALL>"
);
list($http_code, $result) = curl_post($url, $header, json_encode($your_big_data));
echo "http_code: $http_code<br>result: $result";

###########################

### Receiver PHP Side: (api.php in our example)
if (function_exists("apache_request_headers")) {$myHeaders = apache_request_headers();}

# See the headers you posted from other side:
print_r($myHeaders);

# See the JSON POST body you posted from other side:
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```